# Make request to php endpoint in angular4

Tags: php, angular

So i am new to Angular4, I have a service that is supposed to make a request to a php api. I have the following code  -

```
getWeather(keyword: string){
  return this.http.get("weather.php",  {
    params: new HttpParams().set('keyword', keyword),
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Method', 'search'),
  });
```

I am getting a 404 localhost:4200/weather.php cannot be found. not sure wher to place the php endpoint file.

Comment: Where does the weather.php file sit on your application?

Comment: i put it in the /app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that localhost:4200 is your front-end server,  you have to set your php server api path in the call. If your php server in in local on the 8080 port, you type `this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/weather.php',...`

Comment: why use absolute urls?

Comment: @madalinivascu this is in case your api backend is different of your front end entry point. If you wand to use 4200 port, create a proxy middleware that redirects to your php server. With angular-cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: I dont have a php server...its just a script file....how do i go about talking to the script from my angular 4 app

Comment: To execute you php script ou need a php server like easyphp. Where is located your file?

Comment: Ok i understand now...This is the correct answer because there is no way to run the php script without a server to seat infront of the script and accept requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in your `src/assets` folder and then call it using `this.http.get("assets/weather.php", {...`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for Angular application is hosted on 4200 port and your PHP file will be using port 80.

Try using

```
http://localhot/path/to/weather.php
```